# geostatistics (determining persistence of roads)

Tags: chi-squared-test

In a study of infrastructural (archaeological) findings i want to determine if findings are found mostly on or near modern roads. I have no clue what statistic test i should use for determining the significance of the results.

By this i mean: are the findings found at random places or are they really significantly found on modern roads?

The situation is as follows: on a map (grid) there is a road network the roads have a bufferzone around them (there are actually several buffer sizes 500m, 1000m and 2000m) on this map archaeological sites are indicated (finds have to do with "older" roads). The question is if say 80% of the total finds is done within the buffer of 500m how significant is that? And what test to use?
How does one determine if the finds are different from random, and is that even a valid question?

Comment: You are going to need to give more detail here. What information do you have? Can you, for instance, determine the area of your study space which is near a road? Can you annotate each finding to its exact location?

Comment: Also, explaining the format of your data would be very helpful. :) Assuming that you can always calculate distance from the site of a finding to the nearest modern road, and if $X=\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ are those distances, I guess that you would be interested in testing the hypothesis that $mean(X)=0$ or $mean(X) \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: I think you need to specify your null hypothesis, i.e. what is the alternative to "mostly near modern roads"? (A simple null might be, e.g., a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).)

Comment: GeoMatt22: Very interesting: Poisson point process, that is a good model for a random distribution of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to test for a proportion. Take a look at [this web page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/53). There you can find out what is testing for a proportion and how to perform such tests. Make sure you follow the examples (especially 8.2.3). You can find more useful links at the bottom and on the top left of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i can test for significance, i am a little concerned by the: "post hoc fallacy", the question is asked after the facts. I have percentages now i can "fit" the test to the outcomes (i am afraid to make the mistake of using statistics to prove my point not to prove a fact).

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are concerned with post hoc fallacy. Each statistical test is associated with two types of errors: Type I Error means rejecting the true null hypothesis, Type II means failing to reject a false null. Their probabilities are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We usually choose $\alpha$ to be $0.01$ or $0.05$. On the other hand, $\beta$ is correlated with the sample size among other things. The quantity $1-\beta$ is called the power of the test, and the sample size is usually chosen so that the power is around $80\%$.

Comment: Yes Milos you are right, you have been a great help. I have to figure the question out better, i have no complete control over it since it's not my research. I am afraid the researcher has not taken care before embarking on his measurements that is why i am concerned about the post hoc fallacy. There is potentially a reasoning flaw in this study, the infrastructural findings are mostly done near building sites or roads, there is far less digging off the roads (remotely) so it is only logical more finds are done near the road network.

Comment: Oh, now I see. In this case, the hypothesis that digging places are near roads might have more statistical justification, but there might be another option to save the study. Split the sample into two sets: the one where the digging places are near a road, and the one containing places that are not. Then, compare their proportions of the places where an actual finding was done. Follow this link for more technical details: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat500/node/55

Comment: I will check everything and split the sample in two sets, further i will follow the links and use the proportion tests. Thank you all!! Great help.